# Can I have multiple ssh keys in my .ssh folder?

Tags: mac, ssh

Can I create multiple ssh keys, and rename them to user friendly names so I know which key is for which website etc.

Is this safe?

e.g:

```
github_id_rsa
github_id_rsa.pub
..
...
```

How will it know which key to check against when connecting?

On my computer now, when I look at known_hosts, they all seem to have the same key after the name of the host??

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Best way to use multiple ssh private keys on one client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client)

Comment: Also, the known host keys are definitely not the same, just look at the ends of the lines for each host.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes you can have different ssh keys. There's very good documentation on the GitHub Help site at [Help.GitHub - Multiple SSH Keys](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys). Essentially you will be using ssh-add to add the extra keys so that the agent can utilize them. Then you set up the ssh hosts config so that any ssh connections to different domains will be looked up here and the appropriate key will be used. good luck!

Comment: Link no longer works

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: The link does indeed work, now at least.

Answer (score 92):

You can modify the file ~/.ssh/config to use different identity file for different servers. Edit the ~/.ssh/config in your favorite editor and add an entry that is appropriate for your situation like so:

```
Host *
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host *.github.*
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id.rsa

Host *.someother.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/someother_id.rsa
```

The first part above sets the defaults for all hosts and the other sections overrides what should be used for each of the hosts matching the patterns. If you have a different username for each of the hosts, then you can add a **User** key followed by the username on the remote to the section.

Comment: This is the most useful answer to this question regardless of the destination whether GitHub or other sites.

Comment: This doesnt work if you have multiple bitbucket accounts and need to have different keys for each unfortunately.

Comment: `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` or `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/foo_id.rsa` might be necessary.

Comment: @JohnLittle Have a look at my answer which solves multi-user account for the same domain.

Comment: You can also use the `-i` switch on the `ssh` command line.

Comment: `Host *.gitlab.*` didn't work for me, I had to use: `Host *gitlab.com`

Answer (score 20):

You can set up multiple ssh keys for any site having multiple user accounts

Below is the example I used to follow in my development for **GitHub.com**

**Config file example** (located at `~/.ssh/config` )

```
#Personal account
 Host github.com-<personal-account-name>
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
 IdentitiesOnly yes



#Organization account
 Host github.com-<organization-name>
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

**At the time of adding a new origin**

For Personal account

```
git remote add origin git@github.com-<personal-account-name>:<personal-account-name>/<repo-name>.git
```

For Organisation account

```
git remote add origin git@github.com-<organization-name>:<organization-name>/<repo-name>.git
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Brilliant! Such approach allows to have multiple ssh-keys for one domain, awesome 

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/<username> 
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<username>
git clone <username>@bitbucket.org:myfancyteam/myfancyproject.git
```

From : https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-additional-ssh-keys/